# Stuck on Nginx index page

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, nginx-location, nginx-config

I have configured my subdomain on route53 to point to my ec2 public IP, right after I did this I got a welcome to nginx page. It was good this far. Now I add a custom cofig file in nginx/sites-available(also did link it to sites-enabled and also reloaded nginx). I don't see anything new. I still see the same welcome page. I wonder why this happened.I also have proxy_pass to :3000 which doesn't seem to work.

Here are the few things I tried and the result I got.

1. changed index.html file as mentioned in the root(/usr/share/nginx/html) - Still welcome page
2. tried server_name with both default_server and my subdomain(http://management.teampapercloud.in) - Still welcome page
3. stopped nginx service with service nginx stop - Surprisingly it still shows welcome page.
4. tried sudo lsof -i :80 (when nginx is running it has 2 diff nginx processed running one with root as user and the other www-data), when nginx is not running sudo lsof -i :80 gives nothing.
5. at this point i wondered if the domain hitting the server at all or not. I tried to ping, got my ec2 ip. tried DNS checker got my ec2 ip.
6. Now I am so frustrated stopped my ec2 instance. Now the welcome page is gone. which means I believe my ec2 instance is doing something to show the page, But I don't know which service.
7. checked top and service --status-all | grep +  I don't see any strange services running nor services like Apache. as apache is not installed at all.
8. As a final try, I even uninstalled nginx. - I still see the same welcome page.
9. Updated all the index.html files I could find - Still same welcome page.

At this point, I am left with no ideas, and don't understand what is happening. Help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is ec2 caching the page? I think you should check the page cache settings.

Comment: Do you mean browser cache? or something else? Where can I check that?

Comment: I do not mean the browser cache. I am not sure, `ec2` can have any page cache settings.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have written, you reloaded nginx, try again (sometimes we forget to check common things):

   - `sudo service nginx -t` # check if configuration syntax is ok
   - `sudo service nginx reload` #reload configuration
   - `sudo service nginx restart` # restart server
2. Another important thing, check realtime log in terminal

   - error log: `tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log`
   - access log: `tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log`
   - and visit the page from browser and check the log in terminal.
   - `Note: Log files can be in different directory in your server.`
     check log files with this: `ls /var/log/nginx/`
3. May be restart the os, if you have access to restart.
4. ec2 can have any page cache settings.
5. Are you using something `cloudflare` name server that can cache a
   page, or, Any proxy server or something, that can cache the page.
6. You can even try `browser incognito window`, force reload in browser
   (`ctrl` + `shift` + `R`).

Comment: I dont know if there is any proxy even before nginx, ec2 cache may be. I have tried what mentioned in all other points, I've created a new ec2 instance and pointed my subdomain to that. That solved the issue, But still couldnt figure out my other instance didnt work.

Comment: But sometimes, anything can be wrong in an OS and anything can be wrong when install nginx. So, why don't you simply setup main domain on newly create ec2 instance and delete the old ec2 instance `(if there has not much extra cost)`?

Comment: I installed nginx many times in vps and sometimes I saw issues that is weird.

Comment: Yeah, that is what i exactly did.

Answer (score 0):

The changes are not being applied because you're not making any changes to `root directory` which is

```
/var/www/html$
```

as this is a default public folder for your web server. Also if you wish you can change this default path to the one you want.

As you can see I have `"index.nginx-debian.html"` which on changing takes effect immediately.

[image: Nginx-web-server]

Comment: As mentioned, I changed all the html pages including those in /var/www/html. It didnt change anything.

Comment: @rbashish It looks like, it is an uncommon and weird problem.